# add class to third child of tr from index 2 to 4

Tags: jquery

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LtRN8/4/)

getting `lastRowIndex='2'` and `currentIndex='4'`

I have to add class to third child of tr from RowIndex 2 to 4.

```
<table id="mytable" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>      
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td></td>    
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td></td>       
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>     
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: will u have more that 5 `<tr>` or will that be all?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this way:

```
$("tr").slice(1,4).children(":nth-child(3)")
```

---

So, Using your variables **lastRowIndex** and **currentIndex**, the query to add *myClass* should be :

```
 $("tr").slice(lastRowIndex-1, currentIndex)
            .children(":nth-child(3)").addClass("myClass")
```

Comment: loxxy i have add and link for demo

Comment: but when i moves up to down then works fine but when move down to up then only one slot selects

Answer (score 0):

Then somehting like this:

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    var thisIndex = $(this).index()
    if(thisIndex >= 2 && thisIndex <= 4){
        $(this).children().eq(2).addClass('red');
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w59u7/)

Althought I upvoted **loxxy** answer, because that's pretty much what I'do just added it for each row.

Comment: add demo link in my quetion

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `filter`? And use `parseInt` before you compare those variables with the `tr` index :

```
//your variables - be sure to use parseInt on them
var lastRowIndex = parseInt('2', 10);
var currentIndex = parseInt('4', 10);

//use filter on the <tr/>s whose indices lie between your variables.
$("tr").filter(function () {
    //get the index and store in variable
    var index = $(this).index();
    //compare
    return index >= lastRowIndex && index <= currentIndex
})
//find the third-child of every filtered <tr/>
.find(":nth-child(3)")
//add the class "color" to it.
.addClass("color");
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/fTV4m/1/

Comment: add demo link in my quetion

Comment: can u pls tell me what youre trying to achieve here?